# How to add Intellisense description to an enum members c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum:

```
/// <summary>
/// Accoun types enumeration
/// </summary>
public enum AcoountTypeTransaction
{
    [Description("Account type debit")]
    Debit = 0,
    [Description("Account type Credit")]
    Credit = 1
}
```

I want to show descriptions on my intellisense, this is only a sample, i have many enums that must be explained. There is a way to do this

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using [*XML document comments*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) In the same manner as you would for the enumeration declaration itself like this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Account types enumeration
/// </summary>
public enum AcoountTypeTransaction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the Debug  constant.
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Account type debit")]
    Debit = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the Credit constant.
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Account type Credit")]
    Credit = 1
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: So simple, I'm was trying it, but putting ``Sumary`` directly over the ``enum member`` Tks a lot.